# Linear operator $T$ on $F^2$ defined by $[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ has cyclic vector for $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In Linear algebra by Hoffman and Kunze,it is given that **"an example of an operator which has a cyclic vector is the linear operator $T$ on $F^2$ which is represented in the standard ordered basis by the matrix $\bigl[ \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr]$"**

My question is HOW?

My argument:Since the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is ***$x^2$***,so its minimal polynomial is ***$x$***.So,the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial are different.By making use of **Theorem:**  $T$ be a linear operator on vector space $V$ of $n$ dimensional. There exists a cyclic vector for T if and only if minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are same....

Hence,$T$ cannot have the cyclic vector.

Please help!!

P.S.

[image]

Please explain stuff  in yellow highlighted text!!

Comment: Why is the minimal polynomial $x?$

Comment: @Itay4:beacause it is monic and irreducible and has the same root as  that of $x^2$.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is $x$, then $T=0$, contradiction.

Comment: @Fred:got it!! thanks

Comment: @Fred:for what reason $\beta =(a,b)\implies g=a+bx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v=(1,0)^T$. Then $Tv=(0,1)^T$. Thus $\{v,Tv\}$ is a basis of $F^2$.

Conclusion: $v$ is a cyclic vector.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP wanted to know what was the error in his argument.

Comment: And that is reason for the downvote ???? In a comment above I told the OP what was the error, and then , in my answer, I showed the existence of a cyclic vector. Please read the question   " My question is HOW?" of the OP and don't be so petty. Thanks !

Comment: I did *not* downvote your answer.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Who else downvoted my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic polynomial of matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ is $x^2$. So it’s minimal polynomial is $x$ or $x^2$. Certainly $x$ is not minimal polynomial, because $x$ don’t annihilate that matrix. Thus $x^2$ is minimal polynomial. The theorem you stated is correct but we can’t use result of that theorem, since it’s proof comes later in the book.

Author explicitly showed $e_1$ is cyclic vector of $T$, i.e. $F^2=Z(e_1;T)=\{g(T)(e_1)\mid g\in F[x]\}$. Let $\beta =(a,b)\in F^2$. Note $T(e_2)=(0,0)$. So $\beta =a\cdot e_1+b\cdot e_2=a\cdot e_1+b\cdot T(e_1)$. Take $g=a+bx$. Clearly $g(T)(e_1)=\beta \in Z(e_1;T)$. Thus $F^2\subseteq Z(e_1;T)$. Trivially $F^2\supseteq Z(e_1;T)$. Hence $F^2=Z(e_1;T)$.

Since $T(e_2)=(0,0)=0\cdot e_2$, we have $e_2$ is eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to eigenvalue $0$. By [example 1 section 7.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632081/861687), $\dim Z(e_2;T)=1$. Thus $Z(e_2;T)\neq F^2$. Hence $e_2$ is not cyclic vector of $T$.

**Edit:** Well, I recently proved the [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4641013/861687) OP used. It’s proof is not trivial.